# How to run one script and bootstrap links into two or more times after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to run the same scripts for all rows to add items! You can see below in the picture
I want to run javascript and bootstrap link after the page load because in this picture you can see when I click on add item button class was not working  [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvvUV.png)

When we click on any option given in the dropdown we should hide the dropdown and show the box [description box output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP2Eu.png) this script given below is ok for the first row and not working for the second row I want to fix it
**This is HTML code**

Petrol
                                                                    Gas
                                                                    Diesal
                                                                    Coal
                                                                    Oil
                                                                    Aviation Kerosene

**This javascript I want to run multi times!**

```
**This script is for hide and show when we type in description box*
[description box output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP2Eu.png)
when we type in this box dropdown should be hide when length will equal to 0 this should hide box and show dropdown it is ok for first row !

<script>
$('.product').keyup(function() {

  // If value is not empty
  if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
    // Hide the element
    $('.PAS').show();
    $('.product').hide();
  } else if ($(this).val().length > 0)
   {
    // Otherwise show it
    $('.PAS').hide();
    $('.product').show();
  }
}).keyup(); // Trigger the keyup event, thus running the handler on page load
  </script>
This script is for hide and show!
  <script>
        document.querySelector(".PAS1").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      const PAS = document.querySelector(".product");
      const PAS2 = document.querySelector(".PAS");
      if (e.target.value === -1) {
        PAS.style.display = "none";

      } else {
        PAS.style.display = "block";
        PAS2.style.display = "none";
      }

    });
    </script>
```

when I click on any option in the dropdown [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft79o.png) it should show a description box [box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2GC.png) it is ok for the first row but I want to run this scripts on all rows
I tried this script on individual js files but it cant run I only want to know how can i run these scripts and links for all rows!
Thank You!